# What is the best substitute font for Calibri within Microsoft Office?

Tags: fonts

I have read that there are a number of issues with the MS designed and default font Calibri. For instance, what is a Calibri replacement that will not change size when opened in say Pages, Docs, or Adobe. Or simply what is a solid sans-serif font that is more universal across apps.
Does this make sense?

Comment: The issue with changing type is often **not** due to Calibri... it's due to Microsoft in general. MS merely assumes all its files will *always* be used with its own apps and makes no effort to assist any transfer to any other app. Any replacement for Calibri most likely won't help and is a more a matter of preference, not technical issues.

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer would be [Carlito](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/carlito), a free metrically compatible font matching the character widths of Calibri. Google made it by modifying another typeface, Lato. Covers the standard four weights of Regular, Italic, Bold, Bold Italic. You'd need to manually switch documents over to it in those apps, though, they wouldn't automatically substitute to it. LibreOffice does the substitution automatically apparently.

As it sounds like you're on a Mac, Arial, Trebuchet and Verdana are fonts installed both on Windows and on Mac. All have very reliable, very extensive character sets.